# Evaluating $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^2}{e^x-1}\,dx$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, complex-analysis, improper-integrals

How can I calculate the value of this improper integral? $$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^2}{e^x-1}\,dx$$

Comment: Have you tried any contours? What techniques have you tried and ran into an obstacle?

Comment: You can try toy contours, as @Clayton pointed out.

Comment: @Dahaka No it’s probably a good idea to ask what the OP has tried. There are ways to evaluate the integral about a rectnagular contour which might be useless to the OP if he knows nothing about contour integration. Giving us techniques he’s tried also allows everybody to gauge what he knows.

Comment: @Dahaka Yeah there are many duplicates of this question.

Answer (score 3):

$$\int_0^\infty (e^x - 1)^{-1} x^2 dx 
\overset{1}{=} \int_0^\infty \sum_{k=1}^\infty e^{-kx} x^2 dx 
\overset{2}{=}\sum_{k=1}^\infty \int_0^\infty x^2 e^{-kx} dx 
\overset{3}{=} \sum_{k=1}^\infty \mathcal L[x^2](k) 
\overset{4}{=} \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{2}{k^3} 
\overset{5}{=} 2\zeta(3) 
\overset{6}{=}2.404113806319188570799476323022899981529972584680997763584...
$$
where:

1. A geometric series was recognized,
2. Tonelli's theorem allowed the interchange of integral and sum,
3. a Laplace transform appeared, $\mathcal L [f(x)](s) := \int_0^\infty f(x)e^{-sx} dx $,
4. so we used the basic identity $\mathcal L [x^n] (s) = n!/s^{n+1}$,
5. the $\zeta$ function allows us to write down a clean exact answer, and finally
6. [Wolfram|Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2%20*%20zeta(3)) was used to get the approximate answer.

Comment: But no geometric series converges to $\frac{-1}{1-e^x}$ for $x>0$ because in this case $e^x>1$.

Comment: @Matematleta if $e^x = 2 > 1$ i.e. $x = \log 2$ then we indeed have
$$ \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^k} = \frac{-1}{1-e^{\log 2}} = 1$$

Comment: If $x>0$  then the series $\sum e^{-kx}$ converges to $\frac{1}{1-e^{-x}}$ which is not equal to $\frac{1}{e^{x}-1}$

Comment: @Matematleta its a sum from 1, not 0, http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+of+x%5E(-n)+from+n%3D1+to+infinity

Comment: Yes, I see. OK! I just noticed the sum starts at $1$.

Comment: I was claiming that $\sum e^{-kx}$ converges to $\frac{1}{1-e^{-x}}$, if $x>0,$ and this is true if the sum starts at $0$.

Comment: @Matematleta Yes, I noticed this when your sum somehow didn't match with the explicit case $x=\log 2$ above, which i memorised since highschool.

Comment: I like your application of Tonelli, with Lebesgue and Counting measure. It lets you avoid the usual uniform convergence argument.  Happy to upvote your answer.

Comment: @Matematleta glad you enjoyed it like I did!

Answer (score 1):

Using [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RiemannZetaFunction.html):
$$\zeta(3)=\dfrac{1}{\Gamma(3)}\int_0^\infty\dfrac{u^2}{e^u-1}\ du$$
where
$$\zeta(3)=\dfrac{5}{2}\sum_{k=1}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k^3{2k\choose k}}$$
is Apéry constant.